# How to configure the parameters for each data node in dolphindb?

Tags: database, cluster-analysis, dolphindb

There are 15 CPU cores for two data nodes: one node owns 7 cores and the other node owns 8 cores. How to configure the parameters for each data node? Seems parameter like “workerNum” in cluster.cfg will be used by both nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify configuration parameter values in the following 4 ways:

1.Node alias qualified configuration parameters. Node aliases are defined in the cluster.nodes file.

```
nodeA.volumes = D:/DFSRoot/nodeA
nodeB.volumes = D:/DFSRoot/nodeB
```

2.(Node alias + wildcard character ("?" or "%")) qualified configuration parameters. "?" represents a single character; "%" represents 0, 1 or multiple characters.

```
%8821.volumes = /DFSRoot/data8821
%8822.volumes = /DFSRoot/data8822
DFSnode?.maxMemSize=16
```

3.Use macro variable  for assignments with node aliases. For a cluster with 2 data nodes nodeA and nodeB:

```
volumes = /DFSRoot/<ALIAS>
```

is equivalent to

```
nodeA.volumes = /DFSRoot/nodeA
nodeB.volumes = /DFSRoot/nodeB
```

4.If the parameters are not qualified by node aliases, they indicate common configuration parameter values for all the data nodes in the cluster.

```
maxConnections=64maxMemSize=12
```